# How to add sugar for NetEncoder?

Tags: syntax, neural-networks, downvalues

I'm tired of the extra level of list in `NetEncoder` and would like to get rid of it.

The obvious thing fails:

```
Unprotect @ NetEncoder;
NetEncoder[s_String, spec__] := NetEncoder[{s, spec}]
```

[image]

Any other ideas? And I guess asking to change the syntax warning is asking too much?

Comment: The input form of `NetEncoder` starts with a string followed by an association. That may explain why the developers have built in a check for the argument pattern. One option would to use another head like `CreateNetEncoder` or `GetNetEncoder`...

Comment: @M.R. developer here -- yes i would agree that you are best off defining `NetEnc[args___] := NetEncoder[{args}];`